# responsive grid template columns with fixed percentage width for one column and auto width for second column

Tags: html, css, css-grid

How can I make a responsive grid that has 2 columns? One should take max 20% of the width and the other should take the rest of the width. This is the CSS that I have so far for that kind of row:

```
const StyledRow = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% auto;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
`
```

And the html is this:

```
    <StyledRow>
      <label htmlFor="firstEmail" style={{justifySelf: 'end', paddingRight: 10}}>Email:</label>
      <Input id="firstEmail" type="email" value={firstEmail} onChange={handleChangeFirstEmail}/>
    </StyledRow>
```

This is not responsive, since on the small width screen the label is still in the same row as the input. How can I achieve that the second column goes under the first column. I have tried also with:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(20%, 80%));
```

Then both columns take 80% of the width, so they end up one over another on big screens.

How can I achieve then that the first column is max 20% wide and the other takes up the rest, while being responsive on small screens?

Comment: Your first block of code is not valid CSS. Please edit it to be the actual CSS or edit your question to be about the languages you are actually using if you're using something other than CSS. See [mcve] for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "fr" unit to take up a fraction of remaining space. So for your second column you use 1fr to take up 1 part of the remain space, or 100%. The fr unit will take into consideration the gaps you have between columns/rows.

```
grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr;
```

As for responsive for small screens use @media queries. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
   grid-template-columns: 1fr;  
}
```